# map two classes to one DB table in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 class Class1.java and Class2.java. Both are mapped to Class Table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Class")
public class Class1 {
 String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Class")
public class Class2 {
  String name;
}
```

Now when my sessionfactory will be created at that time both the class will be scanned and both will consume memory.

But in my application when it boot up we are deciding at runtime which class will be used in whole application either Class1.java or Class2.java by looking into database.

So I want hibernate to use either of the class Class1.java or Class2.java so that I can save memory. Please help with this issue.

Comment: Is this even possible?

Comment: currently when sessionfactory is initialized it will scan both the class. but we want sessionfactory scan either of the class not both.

Comment: Hmm, you could try and register the classes manually (something along the lines described here: http://portofino.manydesigns.com/en/blog/configuring-hibernate-programmatically). Depending on your environment (e.g. when running in a jpa enviroment) that might be hard though - any chance you could decide between the classes at compile or deploytime, i.e. something like a plugin/module system?

Comment: @Thomas : The link provided by you is seems to be not available. We are deciding which class will be used when our web application is booting up. we are using Spring Hibernate and Java.

Comment: Sorry, had an excess character in the link. This should do: http://portofino.manydesigns.com/en/blog/configuring-hibernate-programmatically - Besides that, if you're deciding at boot time it should be doable. I'm no Spring expert though, so I can't tell you where exactly that configuration should go (just as an idea you might also try and put the classes into two separate jars and only load one of them).

Comment: @Thomas : This will be difficult to manage because we have more than 200 class whose duplicate copy we have to maintained.

Comment: Hmm, in that case another thing you could try (if manually registering classes won't work, try that first) would be to employ a custom classloader and not load or alter the classes you don't want to use. That, however, depends on whether you can add a custom classloader, when the classes are loaded and whether you have the necessary information by then.

Answer (score 0):

We are able to do it in following way.

We are using Spring so used the concept of creating bean by annotation i.e. JavaConfig.

for e.g.

```
@Configuration
public class BeanFactory {

@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource); // datasource injected using @Autowire
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String[] packageToScan = new String[] {"your package"};
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("", "", "");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("query to get packagetoscan property.");
        if (resultSet.next()){
            packageToScan[0] = resultSet.getString(1);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(packageToScan);
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties()); // hibernateProperties() method will return properties.
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

so this way we can change packagetoscan property in database and when our application is booting up it will get this property from database and we are able to save memory.